# Many-to-many relationships ERD

Tags: php, mysql, database, relationship, erd

I'm currently designing a database design for a thesis repository. I came across this situation:

• A student can submit ONLY ONE thesis, and a thesis can be submitted by MANY students.

However, I do not want to make the Thesis ID repeat for the Thesis table. 
Should I use a junction table? I have made an initial design (below) with one. Am I in the right track?

[image]

Comment: "However, I do not want to make the Thesis ID repeat for the Thesis table." Why not?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Only I have a comment on the `Thesis_Students` table, I see you have both `ThesisID` and `StudentID` as PK, which will cover that, one student should be related to a Thesis only once. But you have an additional condition "A student can submit ONLY ONE thesis". So you need an additional `UNIQUE` constraint with only `StudentID`, so that no more than one entry for any `StudentID` can be inserted. (Well actually, in which case your PK for `ThesisID` + `StudentID` not needed anymore, since you cannot anyhow insert more than one entry for the `StudentID`).

Comment: Does it mean the StudentID will have 3 keys? @TareqMahmood

Comment: How? You have one with `UNIQUE` constraint and another jointly with `ThesisID`, which one is the third one?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm thinking of removing the Thesis_Students table and putting a `StudentsID` in the Thesis Table with a Unique Constraint. Is that it? @TareqMahmood

Comment: No, In that case, how do you add multiple students for the same thesis? But if you want to remove the `Thesis_Students` table you can add the `ThesisID` in `Students` table and you don't need any additional `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TahreqMahmood! I got it.

Comment: Last clarification though: The junction table will still be there, but now removing the StudentID PK and adding it as a unique key? Or can I add it as Unique and FK?

Comment: If you remove StudentID from PK, you need to remove ThesisID too from PK (That means remove the PK altogether), otherwise ThesisID will become UNIQUE and you will not be able to add multiple student for the same thesis

Comment: If I remove the two `PKs`, then the junction table will not have one? Or could I just use an auto_increment?

Comment: No, just make the `StudentID` as PK

Comment: Thanks! @TareqMahmood Hope to ask again in the future. :D

Comment: You are most welcome. Pls accept / upvote the answer if it helped you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that just put thesisID column on Students Table,