# Consolidation of two entities in one table

Tags: php, mysql, database, relationship

I am making a thesis repository, and I came across another situation. I have 3 user levels, admin, staff and guest. I have this ERD diagram below. 
Situation: A user can be a student, admin or staff. However, one feature of this web app is to search theses by authors. Also, a user with admin / staff privilege upload thesis.
Question: Can I consolidate student and other user privilege information in one table? Say like, all info will be stored in one table called users?   Thanks in advance

[InitialERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwcY0.png)

Comment: You have three user levels admin, staff & a guest. Then what is a student. Isn't that a fourth user level?

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks or that answer.

Comment: As I guess, you are the person who asked this question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215414/many-to-many-relationships-erd/34215473?noredirect=1#comment56176249_34215473. Why I see a different user name here?

Comment: I'm a teammate of the person who asked there. We're working on the same ERD. However, we throw ideas at each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. If a user can have multiple privileges for an instance both a student & staff. 
Then you should have a user table with a one to many relationship with a user privilege table. User privilege table will contain the user privileges like student, guest, admin etc.

B. If a user will have exactly one privilege then you can include that within the user table as a field/column String privilegeKind;